# Unable to generate OpenSSL::PKey object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to generate a openSSL::Pkey using public key but i am getting the following error message "OpenSSL::PKey::RSAError: Neither PUB key nor PRIV key: nested asn1 error"

This is the public key:

> -----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
>   MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAttI6ImgD74PhHWVqnrqSOmStboplyL02DB3/nc2iyDdYLzXoBIQN+NPMBPlsZlEKuKjsg5Ycfp6VjcmncM3CH9MGIr+Lmbj1HZmO/jJGJ84RPhzYOiZuElzs3seIcOtOa3BpFeqRsXJlrf1IVBKVU3erka5ACLVyrsjmp/VXMx5QjPD0qXARMGb6rDewTkyg3pGz07Y7rZgXkTl54ase+XaPegOankxdEQhVjPdrk7eSlIQS5Ni7FAcSyTOtYoPgiP7W0PolOMHvpFg96CHjc8V8xDsFdh0wbHd49WcKxiJMIfL65VUIW5aob9fw05a5FczyASa0iNtRiICy/QnCqQIDAQAB
>   -----END PUBLIC KEY-----

This the code which is generating the error

```
OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new (Base64.decode64(public_key))
```

Anyone know how to fix it and can tell whats wrong with the key. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. You don't need to decode base64 manually.
2. Make sure that the key is formatted correctly: `BEGIN PUBLIC KEY` and `END PUBLIC KEY` should be on separate lines.

Working example:

```
require "openssl"

key = "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\n" \
"MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAttI6ImgD74PhHWVqnrqSOmStboplyL02DB3/nc2iyDdYLzXoBIQN+NPMBPlsZlEKuKjsg5Ycfp6VjcmncM3CH9MGIr+Lmbj1HZmO/jJGJ84RPhzYOiZuElzs3seIcOtOa3BpFeqRsXJlrf1IVBKVU3erka5ACLVyrsjmp/VXMx5QjPD0qXARMGb6rDewTkyg3pGz07Y7rZgXkTl54ase+XaPegOankxdEQhVjPdrk7eSlIQS5Ni7FAcSyTOtYoPgiP7W0PolOMHvpFg96CHjc8V8xDsFdh0wbHd49WcKxiJMIfL65VUIW5aob9fw05a5FczyASa0iNtRiICy/QnCqQIDAQAB\n" \
"-----END PUBLIC KEY-----"

p OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(key)
```

Comment: Hi eyevan, I am still getting same error. Please find my irb output:
OpenSSL::PKey::RSAError: Neither PUB key nor PRIV key: nested asn1 error
 from (irb):7:in `initialize'
 from (irb):7:in `new'
 from (irb):7
 from /home/organizer/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.7/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
2.3.7 :008 >

Comment: @user1969191please paste the code you are executing. Also please try pasting the example above into a file and running it and see if that works for you.